# Msi: Can't set a property from command line

Tags: command-line, properties, wix, windows-installer

I want to change property of msi from command line but it fail. in the log of the msi i can see that my property update with my value but after this it override by action that modified this property.

to be more specific i write: INSTALLFOLDER="*".
but in the msi database has action call SetINSTALLFOLDER that override this value.

i ask how can i skip on this action or disable it from command line.

the msi product not produced by me.

the log:

```
MSI (s) (F4:1C) [15:38:41:973]: Command Line: INSTALLDIR=C:\\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ugi21xcf.3lp
*
*
MSI (s) (F4:1C) [15:38:42:017]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding INSTALLDIR property. Its value is 'C:\\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ugi21xcf.3lp'.
*
*
MSI (s) (F4:1C) [15:38:42:050]: Doing action: SetINSTALLFOLDER
MSI (s) (F4:1C) [15:38:42:050]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 15:38:42: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (F4:1C) [15:38:42:050]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding INSTALLFOLDER property. Its value is 'C:\Tools'.
```

Comment: note the relatively low number of followers for your selected tags. I would add a tag for your version of windows, but this Q may really be more appropriate to superuser.com or serverfault.com. If you post there, please delete this copy of the Q, as duplicate postings are bad etiquette on the StackExchange network of sites. Good luck!

Comment: Whoever created the MSI must be setting that property for a reason, so talk to the person who created it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set false condition to CustomAction which overrides your property but i wouldn't recommend it unless you're 100% confident in what it does (like that all it do is just set INSTALLOCATION). To make it more safe you can create your own CustomAction which will use different property passed from commandline and will override INSTALLOCATION right after SetINSTALLFOLDER CA.

Comment: 1) how can i set false condition to action from command line. 2) I can't create my custom action, i get this msi file as a given.

Comment: For msi editing you can use Orca or Insted-it. If you can not modify msi itself (It's a bad idea to modify installer unless you created it) You can create a transform file for it. Applying transform to an msi makes it as-if edited but original database is not altered. To apply transform during installation you have to specify it in commandline: 
"msiexec.exe /i myprod.msi TRANSFORMS=c:\install\mytransform.mst"
Also you can use Orca/instedit to look inside your msi and to see if your naughty custom action rely on some properties.
By setting false condition I meant something like "1=2"

Comment: Thanks, i remove the SetINSTALLFOLDER action in transforms file and now it work like i want. i didn't know before the Transform method.